# clone system call's argument stores in stack or somewhere else?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, stack, clone

Lets take a very simple usage of `clone(2)`

```
int stack_func(void *arg)
{
    *(int*)arg = 10;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 50;
    clone(stack_func, malloc(1024*1024) + (1024*1024), SIGCHLD, &a);
    sleep(2); //Just to be sure
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

From the man-page of `clone()` it is specified both parent and child are allowed to share the memory, the `printf()` in parent process should print 10 not 50. But it's not happening. Why?

- As the child's stack starts with `stack_func` at the top, where will be the `*arg` (not `variable arg`) stored?
- Why the child process gets a new copy when it modifies the reference of `arg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to use the flag `CLONE_VM`:

```
clone(stack_func, malloc(1024*1024) + (1024*1024), SIGCHLD | CLONE_VM, &a);
```

> **CLONE_VM** (since Linux 2.0)
>
> If **CLONE_VM** is set, the calling process and the child process run in the same memory space. In particular, memory writes performed by the calling process or by the child process are also visible in the other process. Moreover, any memory mapping or unmapping performed with mmap(2) or munmap(2) by the child or calling process also affects the other process.
>
> If **CLONE_VM** is not set, the child process runs in a separate copy of the memory space of the calling process at the time of `clone()`. Memory writes or file mappings/unmappings performed by one of the processes do not affect the other, as with fork(2).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `CLONE_VM` flag. From [the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html):

> If CLONE_VM is set, the calling process and the child process
>                 run in the same memory space.  In particular, memory writes
>                 performed by the calling process or by the child process are
>                 also visible in the other process.  Moreover, any memory
>                 mapping or unmapping performed with mmap(2) or munmap(2) by
>                 the child or calling process also affects the other process.
>
> If CLONE_VM is not set, the child process runs in a separate
>                 copy of the memory space of the calling process at the time of
>                 clone().  Memory writes or file mappings/unmappings performed
>                 by one of the processes do not affect the other, as with
>                 fork(2).

```
clone(stack_func, malloc(1024*1024) + (1024*1024), CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, &a);
```

Comment: Read the clone manpage carefully though, the syscall and the c library function are slightly different.